# Pasar array de JavaScript a PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

estoy trabajando en un formulario en PHP y necesito pasar desde JavaScript los datos de un array a PHP. Los datos provienen de una tabla

```
    <table id="tabla" class="tablaDetalle" style="background-color:lightgrey;height:auto; width: 700px;" border="1">
        <thead>
      <tr><th colspan="5" style="background: #4CAf50; text-align: center;">Detalle de Compra</th></tr>
            <tr><th style="background: #4CAF50;">Cantidad</th>
                <th style="background: #4CAF50;">Descripción</th>
                <th style="background: #4CAF50;">Bruto</th>
                <th style="background: #4CAF50;">Descuento</th>
          <th style="background: #4CAF50;"></th></tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody id="t_cuerpo">
        <tr>
          <td><input type="number" value="1" min="1" name="cantidad"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="descripcion" required></td>
            <td><input type="number" name="bruto" min="0" value="0"></td>
            <td><input type="number" name="descuento" min="0" max="100" value="0"></td>
          <td><button class='remove'>-</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
          <input type="button" id="addRow" style="font-size:12px; padding: 8px 12px;" value="Nueva Fila" class="botonverde" />
          <button type="button" id="obtener">Obtener</button>
```

La tabla posee un script que genera y elimina filas

```
<script>
var html = "<tr><td><input type='number' value='1' min='1' name='cantidad'></td><td><input type='text' name='descripcion'></td><td><input type='number' name='bruto' min='0' value='0'></td><td><input type='number' name='descuento' min='0' max='100' value='0'></td><td><button class='remove'>-</button></td></tr>" ;

$(function() {
    $('tbody').sortable();

    $('#addRow').click(function(){
        $('#tabla > tbody:first').append(html);
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
        $(this).parents('tr').remove();
    });
</script>
```

Para probar que los datos ingresados generé un array e hice este script

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

  $('#obtener').click(function() {
    var lista = [];
    $('#t_cuerpo input').each(function() {
      var valor_input = $(this).val();
              lista.push(valor_input);
    });
        $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "ingresocompras.php",
       datatype: 'JSON',
       data: {lista: JSON.stringify(lista)},
       success: function(data){
            alert("success:",data);
        },
       failure: function(errMsg) {
            alert("error:",errMsg);
       }
    });
    alert(lista);
  });
});
</script>
```

Para probar que de JavaScript envie los datos mediante JSON a PHP, hice este codigo pero el problema es que solo genera el array que lo puedo comprobar con el "alert(lista)", pero no envia los datos por JSON

```
<?php
    $data = json_decode($_POST["lista"]);
    echo $_POST["lista"];
    var_dump($data);
?>
```

Si alguien lee esto, hice algunos cambios en el script y me di cuenta de algunas cosas. Como soy nuevo en el uso de JS y Ajax, no puedo encontrar la solucion

Mi nuevo script es

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

  $('#obtener').click(function() {
    var lista = new Array();
    $('#t_cuerpo input').each(function() {
      var valor_input = $(this).serialize();
              lista.push(valor_input);
    });
    var cadena = JSON.stringify(lista);
       $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "ingresocompras.php",
       datatype: 'JSON',
       data: { "cadena" : cadena },
       success: function(data){
            console.log("success:",data);
        },
       failure: function(errMsg) {
            alert("error:",errMsg);
       }
    });
    alert(cadena);
  });
});
</script>
```

Efectivamente alert(cadena) me devuelve lo que quiero gracias al serialize(). Pero el gran problema es el "console.log(success,data)". Al ejecutarlo, me DEVUELVE TODO EL DOCUMENTO. Algo asi

```
"success:   
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
"
```

No entiendo cual es el error, he buscado y no tengo ninguna solución

Comment: Pon la parte del código del servidor, porque lo más posible es que estés devolviendo el html , de vez de una petición json , por medio del json_encode , piensa que luego hay que hacer `var datos = JSON.parse(data); console.log(datos.contenido);` siendo contenido lo que te interesa.

Answer (score 2):

Sin la parte del servidor poco te puedo decir (cuando lo pongas editaré el post y te intentaré contestar mejor) pero fíjate con el explorador de `Network` en Chrome o el navegador que tengas.
Siempre recomiendo lo mismo , hacer `echos`,`var_dump` , a lo largo del código y verlo en este caso con `Network` para ver el comportamiento , sino desde un IDE , haces un seguimiento paso a paso.

Por lo general funciona así la comunicación entre servidor y página.

## Parte del servidor

```php
$dato = [
    'estado' => 200,
    'datos' => [['paco','3€','patatas'],...]
];
echo json_enconde($dato);
exit();
```

## Parte JS

El código no lo he comprobado pero es para que cojas el concepto. Las peticiones pro ajax tienen que ir en JSON , por consiguiente desde el servidor como ves hice `json_encode` , JS , tiene su propia función para estas cosas que es el `JSON.parse()` , para parsear el objeto JSON a un objeto comprensible para él.

```js
  $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "ingresocompras.php",
       datatype: 'JSON',
       data: { "cadena" : cadena },
       success: function(data){
            var peticion = JSON.parse($data); //array tabla
            $.each(peticion,function(i,e){ //i = index , e = elemento
                 $('#tabla').append('<tr><td>'+e[0]+'</td><td>'+e[1]+'</td><td>'+e[2]+'</td></tr>')
            });
        },
       failure: function(errMsg) {
            alert("error:",errMsg);
       }
});
```

## Inspeccionar con el navegador

Para que veas como hacerlo en Chrome sería :

1. Secundario en la página web , `inspeccionar`.
2. Click en `Network`.
3. Haces las peticiones y vas viendo su comportamiento con el tipo de `status`. Que te salga.